# WPF Browser Application Null Reference Error

Tags: .net, wpf, windows

I have this code but its giving me a NullReference Error whenever I built it on Line 22.
Can I know where I am making my mistakes.

Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class Page4 : Page
{

    DispatcherTimer introTime = new DispatcherTimer();

    public Page4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        introTime.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
        introTime.Tick += new EventHandler(introTime_Tick);
        introTime.Start();
    }

    private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void introTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.IsChecked == false)
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: and line 22 is which line ?

Comment: the line after the button1 check

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to access NavigationService before it is instantiated. You could override `OnLoaded` and do the `Timespan.Tick` bit in the body.

The result will look something like this

```
private void introTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button1.IsChecked == false)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}

void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    introTime.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
    introTime.Tick += new EventHandler(introTime_Tick);
    introTime.Start();

}
```

[WPF Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-5)

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error on the OnNavigatedTo. It shows that "no suitable method found to override".

Comment: My mistake on that one this should set you straight.

Comment: Why is the timer needed at all, why not just check the state of the button in OnLoad?

Comment: I assumed there was some other reason for the timer. I have no idea. probably should ask OP.